# trigger a function on DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little function :

```
$('.chrnumberpickerDiv select').change(function(){
    var sel = $(this),
    value = sel.closest('.chrnumberpickerDiv').find('.chrnumberpickerDivText');
    value.text(sel.find(':selected').text());
}).one('change');
```

My problem is that I also need to trigger it on DOM load. I have tried `.trigger('change')` instead of `.one('change')` but it seems like it goes in a loop and never stops refreshing my page. So what could I be doing to trigger the event on DOM but without causing any damages to other events or whatever makes the function go in a loop ?

Comment: unless there is some part of the API i'm not aware of, `.one('change');` doesn't do anything (binds an undefined handler to change event, maybe?)

Comment: I think you got me wrong. This function loads on DOM, but I need it to execute it so I can fill a div with the text from an option, as the div is empty until the change is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you need to trigger a function when the select changes, as well as programmatically trigger it when the page loads to populate an initial value:

```
// define the handler
var changeHandler = function() {
    var sel = $(this),
    value = sel.closest('.chrnumberpickerDiv').find('.chrnumberpickerDivText');
    value.text(sel.find(':selected').text());
};

// bind the handler
$('.chrnumberpickerDiv select').change(changeHandler);

$(document).ready(function () {
    // execute the handler on page load
    // use proxy to change what "this" means in the handler
    // (jQuery does this for you when you bind a handler through jQuery)
    $.proxy(changeHandler, $('.chrnumberpickerDiv select')[0]));
});
```

[Documentation for proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Comment: Yeah ... this could look like something I need ... just that when tested it doesn't actually do anything on page load, just when the change is triggered :|

Comment: @Roland is there a value selected initially in the select? if there isn't, `sel.find(':selected').text()` would be empty.

Comment: Yes, there is a value by default in the select.

Comment: There are in fact two options inside with values, not an actual value or text

Comment: @Roland what's coming back from the jQuery selectors in the change handler? if you make a jsfiddle we can help debug.

Comment: The thing is that the content it's generated with .net ... so there's not much I can add in the fiddle that could help :| There may be other functions interfering with this one, or other events maybe ... I know that it works fine when just doing the change event without the trigger one, just when I'm running the trigger so the value from the option can be grabbed and placed in the div is when the page refreshes infinitely ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chrnumberpickerDiv select').change(function(){
        var sel = $(this),
        value = sel.closest('.chrnumberpickerDiv').find('.chrnumberpickerDivText');
        value.text(sel.find(':selected').text());
    }).one('change');
});
```

you have be careful not to assign multiple change functions. Otherwise all of them are called when the change event happens.